# Which suits my location streaming scenario better? AWS Kinesis, SQS or Other?

Tags: geolocation, publish-subscribe, amazon-sqs, amazon-kinesis, stream-processing

We are designing a location streaming solution for our truck fleet management web app where our Android and iOS apps for drivers would send location updates (lat, long, timestamp and vehicle id) each 15 seconds or so to the backend in AWS. The RESTful mobile backend (based on .Net WebAPI) is hosted in beanstalk. The back office web app (ASP.Net based and also hosted in beanstalk) would allow real-time viewing of trucks and their locations in a map.

When the web app user first launches the map screen, it would be required to load the truck location indicators that fall within the visible map area based on the most recent location update and then change their locations in real time based on the incoming location updates and visible map area.

So the setup I envision is something similar to

```
Mobile App (AWS SDK) --(Location Updates)--> AWS Kinesis --> ? --> Web App
```

This needs to be scalable upto around 5000 trucks. I've been reading conflicting articles on the internet that for pub/sub SQS is better suited than Kinesis, but also SQS can be much much costlier than Kinesis in the long term. e.g. [this](https://theburningmonk.com/2018/04/what-is-the-best-event-source-for-doing-pub-sub-with-aws-lambda/)

I've also entertained the idea of going with Redis pub/sub. I'm also certain that pub/sub alone would not do the job as we may need to query the the most recent distinct truck locations that fall within a provided bounded rectangle in the map (initial load scenario).

1. Is Kinesis the right choice? If not what's better? (cost is a huge concern for us)?
2. For the solution proposed in 1, what's the best way to push/pull location updates into the web app? (indicated in the above flow by a question mark)
3. I'd like to skip sending location data through beanstalk and send it directly to Kinesis (or to the solution proposed in 1) to minimize the cost. Would this be a viable solution?

Thank you in advance.